# how to move from one row to another

Tags: java, database

[image: this is my shape of database]

I've set my labelTEXT to "T26 content". Then, i want to changet the labelTEXT content to "T30 content" by click "Yes Button" (ps: T26 have T30 IF_YES value). When i click "Yes Button" again, labelTEXT content should change to T25 content. how to do that?

```
private void btYesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    Connection conn = connectionClass.GetConnections();
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    String task;
    task = "T26";
    try {
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * FROM task where ID = '"+task+"'");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String TEXT = rs.getString("TEXT");
            String IF_YES = rs.getString("IF_YES");
            labelTEXT.setText(TEXT);
            task = IF_YES;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

hope this clear enough

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: i try to edit it. thank you

Comment: You do it by not hardcoding `"T26"`, but instead make `task` an instance field, initialized to `"T26"`. You should also change code to use `PreparedStatement`, change SQL to `select * FROM task where ID = ?`, and call `stmt.setString(1, task)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would query again for the row corresponding to the new ID based on what the user clicked.

Edit:
Look up prepared statements, as they are a safe way to do things http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html.

Building from your existing code, it should do something like the following for the queries. The UI and control flow logic will have to be filled in:

```
private void btYesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    Connection conn = connectionClass.GetConnections();
    boolean done = false;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;
    String task;
    task = "T26"; // Set initial value of task
    // Assuming one row expected (may want to handle error case later)
    query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE ID = ? LIMIT 1"

    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        while (!done) {
            pst.setString(1, task)
            rs = pst.executeQuery()
            while (rs.next()) {
                String TEXT = rs.getString("TEXT");
                String IF_YES = rs.getString("IF_YES");
                labelTEXT.setText(TEXT);
                task = IF_YES; // Task is now updated for the next loop
            }
            // TODO: Make sure to set done to false when all tasks complete.
        }

        pst.close()
        conn.close()
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Note: you may also want to look into making multiple queries into transactions if needed https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html.